# MySql & Entity Framework causing "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, entity-framework, nullreferenceexception

Forgive me if this is somewhat vague...I am using MySql connector for an Entity Framework based application.

I have a record in my Content table, which I am trying to fetch, but Whenever it tries to get the record, I'm getting this exception:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

at this line:

```
Data.Entities.Content content = this.SiteData.Content.Take(1).SingleOrDefault();
```

I've checked that SiteData is an instance (...it is), however when I inspected `Content`, it appeared not to have any records, so I'm assuming that `Take(1)` fails...I could be wrong.

Here is the stack trace:

> [NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an
>   object.]
>   MySql.Data.Entity.SelectStatement.GetDefaultColumnsForTable(TableFragment
>   table) +64
>   MySql.Data.Entity.SelectStatement.GetDefaultColumnsForFragment(InputFragment
>   input) +90
>   MySql.Data.Entity.SelectStatement.AddDefaultColumns(Scope scope) +87
>   MySql.Data.Entity.SelectStatement.Wrap(Scope scope) +37
>   MySql.Data.Entity.SelectGenerator.WrapIfNotCompatible(SelectStatement
>   select, DbExpressionKind expressionKind) +69
>   MySql.Data.Entity.SelectGenerator.Visit(DbLimitExpression expression)
>   +37    System.Data.Common.CommandTrees.DbLimitExpression.Accept(DbExpressionVisitor`1
>   visitor) +25
>
>   MySql.Data.Entity.SqlGenerator.VisitInputExpression(DbExpression e,
>   String name, TypeUsage type) +35
>
>   MySql.Data.Entity.SelectGenerator.VisitInputExpressionEnsureSelect(DbExpression
>   e, String name, TypeUsage type) +21
>
>   MySql.Data.Entity.SelectGenerator.Visit(DbProjectExpression
>   expression) +38
>
>   System.Data.Common.CommandTrees.DbProjectExpression.Accept(DbExpressionVisitor`1
>   visitor) +25
>   MySql.Data.Entity.SelectGenerator.GenerateSQL(DbCommandTree tree) +60 
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices.CreateDbCommandDefinition(DbProviderManifest
>   providerManifest, DbCommandTree commandTree) +329
>   System.Data.Common.DbProviderServices.CreateCommandDefinition(DbCommandTree
>   commandTree) +125
>   System.Data.EntityClient.EntityCommandDefinition..ctor(DbProviderFactory
>   storeProviderFactory, DbCommandTree commandTree) +1411
>   System.Data.EntityClient.EntityProviderServices.CreateCommandDefinition(DbProviderFactory
>   storeProviderFactory, DbCommandTree commandTree) +78
>   System.Data.EntityClient.EntityProviderServices.CreateDbCommandDefinition(DbProviderManifest
>   providerManifest, DbCommandTree commandTree) +159
>   System.Data.Common.DbProviderServices.CreateCommandDefinition(DbCommandTree
>   commandTree) +125
>   System.Data.Objects.Internal.ObjectQueryExecutionPlan.Prepare(ObjectContext
>   context, DbQueryCommandTree tree, Type elementType, MergeOption
>   mergeOption, Span span, ReadOnlyCollection`1 compiledQueryParameters,
>   AliasGenerator aliasGenerator) +453
>
>   System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ELinqQueryState.GetExecutionPlan(Nullable`1
>   forMergeOption) +736
>   System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1
>   forMergeOption) +131
>   System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator()
>   +36    System.Linq.Enumerable.SingleOrDefault(IEnumerable`1 source) +179    System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.b__2(IEnumerable`1
>   sequence) +41
>
>   System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.ExecuteSingle(IEnumerable`1
>   query, Expression queryRoot) +59
>   System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.System.Linq.IQueryProvider.Execute(Expression
>   expression) +133
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.DbQueryProvider.Execute(Expression
>   expression) +87    System.Linq.Queryable.SingleOrDefault(IQueryable`1
>   source) +251    SamsCreative.Home.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs
>   e) in g:\Software
>   Development\Projects\SamsCreative\SamsCreative\Home.aspx.cs:17
>   System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender,
>   EventArgs e) +51    System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +92
>   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +54
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   +772

I'm really at a loss as to what is causing this...any help will be much appreciated!

Comment: Try `var content = this.SiteData.Content.Take(1).SingleOrDefault();`; Another thing, what's the content of `this`?

Comment: @Tico...Okay, I've tried using var instead of specifying the exact type...same problem!. Content "should" refer to a simple entity consisting of some strings and a few decimals. this.SiteData is a reference to the DbContext instance

Comment: Hum...Try this: `YourDbContext xxx = new YourDbContext();
var query = (from p in xxx select p).FirstOrDefault();` Instantiate you DbCOntext first.

Comment: Ah! FirstOrDefault(); did the trick! :-) Thank you!

Comment: Nice! Glad I could help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the "comments":

Hum...Try this:

```
YourDbContext xxx = new YourDbContext();
var query = (from p in xxx select p).FirstOrDefault();
```

Instantiate you DbContext first.

Answer (score 0):

You should add dbConfigurationType attribute on your dbContext.

```
    [DbConfigurationType(typeof(MySqlEFConfiguration))]
    public class MysqlDbContext: DbContext
    {
        //Add your Dbsets here

        public MysqlDbContext()

            //Reference the name of your connection string
            : base("ConnectionStringName")
        {
        }
    }
```